# Loading .style file?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, style

I have a file Trees.style that I'm trying to load into ArcGIS 10.0  I can't get it to be recognized.

Can somebody point me to detailed (read bonehead) loading directions?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve - just having all the styles available to apply the manually to a layer or using "match to symbols in a style"?

Answer (score 4):

Style files can be loaded from anywhere on your system.

There are two schools of thought here:

1. Keep them where the system style files are and the system can get to them easily.
2. Keep them on a shared drive where everybody can get to them and add to them.

There are pluses and minuses to both.
I adhere to No. 2.
Sharing is better.

[image]

In Customize there is a style manager.
In style manager you can load your file and/or load other provided style files.

The default location (No.1 above) for style files is...

```
c:\users\username\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop 10.x\ArcMap\
```

[image: Location]

But especially the later versions do a good job of holding this info, so maybe my method is a bit old school now.

I create my own folder for styles and point to it in manager.
Then all of my users can load the same style file.
If your style file is corrupt you might be able to [restore it using this blog](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2007/10/30/tips-for-managing-style-files/).

Comment: +1 I also will sometimes make a copy of a .style file and keep it with the rest of my data for a particular project, that way if someone needs to make edits or new maps months or years later, the style is readily accessible.

Comment: Also keep in mind it is a database and can be corrupted. I haven't seen this too often but a backup is a good idea